Can not extract more than one key when looping over an array with jq in bash
This works:
#!/bin/sh -e

cat << EOF > error.json
[
  {
    "path": "path1",
    "path_with_namespace": "path_with_namespace1"
  },
  {
    "path": "path2",
    "path_with_namespace": "path_with_namespace2"
  }
]
EOF

jq -c '.[]' error.json | while read PROJECT; do
  # This works
  PATH_WITH_NAMESPACE=$(echo "$PROJECT" | jq .path_with_namespace)
  echo "Shallow cloning $PATH_WITH_NAMESPACE ..."
done

Output:
$ ./error.sh 
Shallow cloning "path_with_namespace1" ...
Shallow cloning "path_with_namespace2" ...

Extracting a second value does not work:
#!/bin/sh -e

cat << EOF > error.json
[
  {
    "path": "path1",
    "path_with_namespace": "path_with_namespace1"
  },
  {
    "path": "path2",
    "path_with_namespace": "path_with_namespace2"
  }
]
EOF

jq -c '.[]' error.json | while read PROJECT; do
  # This works
  PATH_WITH_NAMESPACE=$(echo "$PROJECT" | jq .path_with_namespace)
  echo "Shallow cloning $PATH_WITH_NAMESPACE ..."

  # This does not
  PATH=$(echo "$PROJECT" | jq .path)
  echo "$PATH"
done

Output:
$ ./error.sh 
Shallow cloning "path_with_namespace1" ...
"path1"
./error.sh: line 18: jq: command not found

I've tried numerous variants of looping over arrays with bash and jq. Basically I can't work with more than one key out of the json file. I need to work with more than one. How would a solution look like?
@0stone0 quoting "$PROJECT" has no effect.

You overwrite the environment variable PATH, so the jq executable cannot be located anymore (resulting in a command not found error). By convention, never use all-caps variable names.

@pmf Thanks! Make it an answer and I will accept it as solution.

This is why you never use all-uppercase names for your own variables.
